# compute a new public key for my RSA private key

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to create a new public key based on a private key. 
 I would like to use something like method in an altered form to generate a new key pair sing the same private key

```
public override string ToXmlString(bool includePrivateParameters)
    {
      RSAParameters rsaParameters = this.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters);
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      stringBuilder.Append("<RSAKeyValue>");
      stringBuilder.Append("<Modulus>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Modulus) + "</Modulus>");
      stringBuilder.Append("<Exponent>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Exponent) + "</Exponent>");
      if (includePrivateParameters)
      {
        stringBuilder.Append("<P>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.P) + "</P>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<Q>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Q) + "</Q>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<DP>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.DP) + "</DP>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<DQ>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.DQ) + "</DQ>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<InverseQ>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.InverseQ) + "</InverseQ>");
        stringBuilder.Append("<D>" + Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.D) + "</D>");
      }
      stringBuilder.Append("</RSAKeyValue>");
      return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

what would be the value for modulus, i believe Exponent stays the same, modulus and  Exponent are both  byte arrays.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What you've shown is the code for RSA.ToXMLString(), but I don't the relevance of that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk, I would like to use the above method in an altered form to generate a new key pair sing the same private key

Comment: "new" keypair is not possible since the keypair is uniquely determined by the private key components. You can get another RSA object with the same keypair by using RSA.FromXMLString.